# KML polygon colouring and mouse clicks

Tags: api, maps, kml, polygons

I'm working with http://workfoldr.com.s118234.gridserver.com/gmaps/ and in the KML file (found @ http://workfoldr.com.s118234.gridserver.com/gmaps/file.kmz) it's clearly stated that there is supposed to be color-filled polygons.

But none are filled in, why?

Also, I might need to bind mouse click events. Is that just a simple event handler in the gmap API?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are not closing the init function after kml();.

For an example of click event see [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html). For all the documentation and more examples see [here](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers).